# How to make TextBox already scrolled-down at all times?

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I'm builing a chatroom in an Access form.

I set up a large `TextBox` control in the form, to contain all the chat messages.

I need to make it scroll down at all times, even when it isn't focused.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Why not contribute to existing open source chat products like: https://about.riot.im/ or https://rocket.chat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
txtBox.selstart = len(txtBox.Value)
```

But where would you call this from? You say at all times even when not focused but to do that you would need a VBA macro running all the time: looking for new messages, adding new messages, and scrolling the box. Access was not designed to work this way.

Access is not a good application to make the front end for a chat room. You can use Access for the back-end: storing the messages, users, and timestamps in tables. I would recommend you use VB.NET to make the front end. VB.NET is multi-threaded so the front end would have the message checking thread adding new messages to the text box while the UI thread can push new messages to the DB where it will be picked up by the new message event and show up in the textbox.